# locationManager not working on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a problem with the refresh information on your GPS position.
The function given by me "locationManager" when you click the button does not refresh the information in the "Label".

My code: http://pastebin.com/hWeq6gTS

I am a novice programmer iOS. Please help.

Comment: Have you enabled Location Services in the project settings?

Comment: your action method is working means have you checked wether it is calling or not,it should be IBAction if you attached it with storyboard or xib.

Comment: Just a quick thought that there's been a location authorization issue since iOS8, so be aware of that.

Comment: johny - main.storyboard - http://i.imgur.com/DFST1d3.png

Answer (score 6):

The issue that is not always obvious with the location services is that you have to have one of these two keys in your Info.plist:

1. `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`
2. `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`

Then, when starting updating of your position, don't forget to request permissions first (again, depending on your requirements (when in use/always):

1. `[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`
2. `[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]`

Comment: @Update - i have a breakpoint 3.1 on line:
[_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

Comment: You should have some value as the string, it probably tries to take out the string from the Info.plist, where you only have the parameter - `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`, but no value.

Comment: The application itself launched, but still the same problem. I do not know why not loading:
- (void) locationManager: (CLLocationManager *) manager

I introduced here NSLog definition, which introduces the information to the log, but it's there does not appear (only the pressed button).

http://i.imgur.com/8349H4i.png

Comment: You need to request the authorization, otherwise it will not start updating.

Comment: It is a request for the location:http://i.imgur.com/7AJvUpy.png

However, after you click the "button" not updating location: http://i.imgur.com/Sgh2TrG.png

Comment: Don't forget that iOS simulator will not give you location updates!

Comment: In the simulator I have included the location and the selected point to which you want to work. So there should be no problems. How will the iPhone to see if it will go (and after buying an Apple Developer Program, damn).

Comment: *No purchase necessary as of iOS9* - http://9to5mac.com/2015/06/10/xcode-7-allows-anyone-to-download-build-and-sideload-ios-apps-for-free/

Answer (score 5):

Add these two properties in info.plist

'NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription' and below property

[image]

Create CocoaTouch Class 'LocationManager' inherit from NSObject like below class.

Singleton Location Manager Class .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface LocationManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *longitude;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *latitude;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *currentLocation;

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;

@end
```

Implementation here .m

```
#import "LocationManager.h"

@implementation LocationManager

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil)
    {
        [self locationManager];
    }
    return self;
}


+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static LocationManager *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[LocationManager alloc] init];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void) locationManager
{
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
        {
            [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    else{

        UIAlertView *servicesDisabledAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Services Disabled" message:@"You currently have all location services for this device disabled. If you proceed, you will be showing past informations. To enable, Settings->Location->location services->on" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue",nil];
        [servicesDisabledAlert show];
        [servicesDisabledAlert setDelegate:self];
    }
}

- (void)requestWhenInUseAuthorization
{
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    // If the status is denied or only granted for when in use, display an alert
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        NSString *title;
        title = (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) ? @"Location services are off" : @"Background location is not enabled";
        NSString *message = @"To use background location you must turn on 'Always' in the Location Services Settings";

        UIAlertView *alertViews = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                             message:message
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil];
        [alertViews show];
    }
    // The user has not enabled any location services. Request background authorization.
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
}


#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
//    [errorAlert show];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    switch (status) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
        {
            // do some error handling
        }
            break;
        default:{
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }
            break;
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    CLLocation *location;
    location =  [manager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
    _currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] init];
    _currentLocation = newLocation;
    _longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",coordinate.longitude];
    _latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",coordinate.latitude];
    //    globalObjects.longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",coordinate.longitude];
    //    globalObjects.latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",coordinate.latitude];
}


@end
```

import

```
#import "LocationManager.h"
```

in your AppDelegate.h

and call that in your AppDelegate.m's like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [LocationManager sharedInstance];
    return true;
}
```

Then just get 
[LocationManager sharedInstance].longitude or latitude for updated lat long.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
 // Location update code
}
```

use this function to get updated location

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
           // Assigning the last object as the current location of the device
           CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

 }
```

Comment: Why post multiple answers if you can edit your existing one?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we do face problem when we do not check the authorisation status. You can check this code

```
        // Custom initialization code
    CLLocationManager *manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    manager.delegate = self;
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    // Setting distance fiter to 10 to get notified only after location change about 10 meter
    manager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

    // Requesting for authorization

    if ([manager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]){
        [manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    // Immediately starts updating the location
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
    [manager startUpdatingHeading];
```

## if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000

```
    // user activated automatic attraction info mode
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied ||
        status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse ||
        status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        // present an alert indicating location authorization required
        // and offer to take the user to Settings for the app via
        // UIApplication -openUrl: and UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString
        [manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

## else

```
    [manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

## endif

Comment: I used your code to request the location and request work. However, no  update coordinates.

Comment: where you are running the application? On simulator or on an iOS device? Are you getting the Location Tracking authorization alert when the app launches?