# Code Not going into DidupdateLocation() method, iOS, objective -c, going into didfailwithError()

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

here is my code :

```
if (!self.locationManager) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy =      kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    }


if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
        [self findCurrentLocation];
        }

-(void)findCurrentLocation {
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {

        [self.locationManager performSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)];
    }

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    self.isLocationEnabled=YES;
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation!= nil) {

        latitudeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        longitudeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    }
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if([error code] == kCLErrorDenied)
    {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
    self.isLocationEnabled=NO;
}
```

i am not getting any errors, but didUpdateToLocation is never called, it is going into didFailWithError ()

I am getting null values for latitude and longtitude. Please let me know what can be done to get values.

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375438/locationmanager-not-working-on-ios-9) it will help to solve your problem approx same problem

Comment: put `NSLog(@"error: %@",error.description);` inside `locationManager:didFailWithError:`. What is the output?

Answer (score 0):

from iOS8 and above:

Add a key to your `Info.plist` and request authorization from the location manager asking it to start.

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

You need to request authorization for the corresponding location method.

```
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]
```

Please Read this Documentation: http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/